# linux pipe argument list too long

Tags: linux, bash, find, pipe

I use the following bash script to remove files older than $days.

```
find /home/xxx/conf_* -maxdepth 0 -mindepth 0 -type d -ctime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

However if the files are more than 32000+, I get

```
/usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

how do I trim the list down to like 20000 only?

Comment: `-exec \;` runs the command once for each file. That's why `-exec \+` was added. That can't be the problem. (Also the error is about `find`.)

Comment: Is that the exact command you are running? What's the value of `$root`? Are there 32000+ paths in `$root`?

Comment: @Etan Reisner: please see updated question for the exact command.  yes there are more than 32000 directories matching the pattern

Comment: Don't glob like that. Let find do the filtering. `find /home/xxx -name 'conf_*' ...`. Also consider using `-exec \+` if your find has it. For that many entries I imagine it might be significantly more efficient.

Comment: @EtanReisner You should post that as an answer, with a `-maxdepth 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment to answer:

Your problem is the glob expansion but you are already using a tool that can perfectly well handle an arbitrary number of found results, namely `find`. As such you should use a glob at all. Instead you should let `find` do all the work.

Something like:

```
find /home/xxx -maxdepth 1 -name 'conf_*' -type d -ctime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Also if your find has `-exec \+` you should probably use this instead:

```
find /home/xxx -maxdepth 1 -name 'conf_*' -type d -ctime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \+
```

For such a large number of matching directories I imagine the significantly reduced amount of executions of `rm` might be significantly more efficient.